# Bottle tries to access a socket in a way forbidden by it's permission

Tags: python, sockets, bottle

I am working with bottle, and have written a simple application

```
from bottle import *

@route("/")
def index():
   return "This is a test."   

run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

When I run this I get an error stating:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\application.py", line 7, in <module>
    run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3117, in run
    server.run(app)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 2771, in run
    srv = make_server(self.host, self.port, app, server_cls, handler_cls)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 153, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 429, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 133, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 440, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbid
den by its access permissions
```

Looking at some other SO posts,it seems to be that I need to allow it through the firewall. I did that:

[image: I let Python through the firewall]

But the error still persists, what do I do to fix this?

Comment: did you try `host="127.0.0.1"`?

Answer (score 1):

Try with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```